# how to make an image into a link

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I have a simple question which I can't seem to solve.

```css
#tps_block {
  height: 45px;
  width: 940px;
}
#tps_point1 {
  width: 351px;
  background: url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_usp.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#tps_point1:hover {
  background: url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_usp.png") 0 -45px no-repeat;
}
#tps_point2 {
  width: 284px;
  background: url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_usp.png") -351px 0 no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#tps_point2:hover {
  background: url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_usp.png") -351px -45px no-repeat;
}
#tps_point3 {
  width: 305px;
  background: url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_usp.png") -677px 0 no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#tps_point3:hover {
  background: url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_usp.png") -677px -45px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="tps_block">
  <div id="tps_point1"><a href="#">Point 1</a>
  </div>
  <div id="tps_point2"><a href="#">Point 2</a>
  </div>
  <div id="tps_point3"><a href="#">Point 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The idea is that there are 3 images side by side, and when the mouse hover's over each image, the image changes to a highlighted one, and the image is clickable too, so that the user is taken to some other place when the image is clicked.

I have managed to apply the hover effect, but I can't get the linking to work.

Can someone help me out ?

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadka/Fjmnt/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're able to change the HTML, just lose the inner `div` tags and apply exactly the same styles to the links themselves:

```
<div id="tps_block">
  <a href="#" id="tps_point1">Point 1</a>
  <a href="#" id="tps_point2">Point 2</a>
  <a href="#" id="tps_point3">Point 3</a>
</div>
```

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fjmnt/7/

Answer (score 2):

Best solution *if* you are unable to modify the HTML.. add the following CSS.

```
#tps_block a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This will fill `<a>` making the entire `div` clickable.

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fjmnt/8/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="tps_block">
  <a href="#"><div id="tps_point1"></div></a>
  <a href="#"><div id="tps_point2"></div></a>
  <a href="#"><div id="tps_point3"></div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: @JoshC As of HTML5, this is okay.  Just looks odd to those of us who grew up on HTML 4.01!

Comment: I grew up on HTML 4.01 than switch to XHTML1.1 than HTML5 ;)